# Custom CSS to change <option> text

Tags: css, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce Store with Product options. I inspected them in my browser and found the following code:

```html
<select class="wcsatt-options-product-dropdown" name="convert_to_sub_dropdown4186">
    <option value="1_month">Am 1 jeden Monat</option>
    <option value="2_month">Am 1 Tag jedes 2 Monats</option>
</select>
```

Now I am a beginner and not very good with CSS. I want to change the texts of the options "Am 1 jeden Monat" and "Am 1 Tag jedes 2 Monats" to another text "example text 1"  and "example text 2" by adding custom CSS to my Website.

What would this custom CSS look like?
Thank you.

Front end:

[image]

Comment: Hi Simon and welcome to Stack Overflow. Just for clarification. You want to replace text in full with some other text rather than alter the text which is there (Eg just the colour and font type)? If so, could I check as to why the text can't be changed directly in the HTML code?

Comment: You have to use JS not CSS.